# Launch Bounds not doing its job?

Tags: c++, cuda, launch, cpu-registers, bounds

This is my visual profiler result for a kernel which I post below. Notice the size of the grid (1) and block (1024) and how it's only using 43 registers when it should be using 64 registers. I'm using a Tesla k40c.

[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "cuda.h"
#include "curand.h"
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include "math.h"
#include <curand_kernel.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

#define iterations 159744
#define transMatrixSize 2592 // Just for clarity. Do not change. 
#define reps 1024 // Is equal to blocksize. Do not change 
#define integralStep 13125  // Number of time steps to be averaged at the tail 

__global__ void
__launch_bounds__(1024,1) 
bufferleech(float *masterForces, float *masterForces50, const float * __restrict__ transMatrix, const float *rands, const int r_max)
{

int globalIdx = ((blockIdx.x + (blockIdx.y * gridDim.x)) * (blockDim.x * blockDim.y)) + (threadIdx.x + (threadIdx.y * blockDim.x));


curandState s;
curand_init (rands[globalIdx] , 0, 0, &s);
float r = 0.0;

volatile __shared__ float buffer[reps]; 
volatile __shared__ float buffer50[reps]; 


int RU[26] = {0};

for(int e =1; e< 25; e++)
{
r = curand_uniform(&s); 
   if(r < .5)
   {
       RU[e] += 10;
   } 
}

int index = 0;
float temp = 0;
float temp50 = 0;

int RUsnapshot = 0; 
int leftsnap = 0;
int RUsnapshot50 = 0; 
int leftsnap50 = 0;



for (int i =0; i < iterations; i++) 
{

leftsnap = 0;
leftsnap50 = 0;
/////////////////////////////////////////XYZ: [100% state][50%Binary][50% state]//////////////////////////////////////
        for(int j = 1; j < 25; j++)
        {
            r = curand_uniform(&s);
            RUsnapshot = int(RU[j]/100);

            //index =  ((((left[j] * dimen2 + right[j]) * dimen3  + RU[j +1 ]) * dimen4) * dimen5) ;
            index =  ((((leftsnap * 6 + int(RU[j+1]/100)) * 6  + int(RU[j]/100)) * 2) * 6) ;

            RU[j]+= 100 * (( r < transMatrix[index]) * (transMatrix[index + 1]) +
                (! (r < transMatrix[index])) * ( r < transMatrix[index + 2]) * (transMatrix[index + 3]) +
                (! ( r < transMatrix[index + 2])) * (r < transMatrix[index + 4]) * (transMatrix[index + 5])) ;

            leftsnap = RUsnapshot;
            //-------------------------------------xTnC 50----------------------------
            RUsnapshot50 = (RU[j] % 10);

            //index =  ((((left[j] * dimen2 + right[j]) * dimen3  + RU[j +1 ]) * dimen4 + xTnC?) * dimen5) ;
            index =  ((((leftsnap50 * 6 + (RU[j+1] % 10)) * 6  + (RU[j] % 10) ) * 2 + int((RU[j] % 100)/10)) * 6) ;

            RU[j]+= ( r < transMatrix[index]) * (transMatrix[index + 1]) +
                (! (r < transMatrix[index])) * ( r < transMatrix[index + 2]) * (transMatrix[index + 3]) +
                (! ( r < transMatrix[index + 2])) * (r < transMatrix[index + 4]) * (transMatrix[index + 5]) ;

            leftsnap50 = RUsnapshot50;
        }


        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////   

         for(int z = 1; z < 25; z++)
        {
            temp+= ((int(RU[z]/100.0)) ==4) + ((int(RU[z]/100.0)) ==5);
            temp50+= ((RU[z] % 10) ==4) + ((RU[z] % 10) ==5);
        }

           buffer[globalIdx] = temp;
           buffer50[globalIdx] = temp50;

  __syncthreads();

   for (int b = 0; b < 10; b++)
   {
      if ((globalIdx % int(powf(2, (b+1)))) == 0)
      {
      buffer[globalIdx] += buffer[globalIdx + int(powf(2,b))];
      buffer50[globalIdx] += buffer50[globalIdx + int(powf(2,b))];
      if(b ==9)
      {
          masterForces[i] = buffer[0]/24576.0;
          masterForces50[i] = buffer50[0]/24576.0;
      }

      }
   }

        temp = 0.0;
        temp50 = 0.0;
}



}
```

How can I get this kernel to use 64 registers?
There is definitely room for more register use as similar kernels I wrote have no problem getting as many as 116 registers with the launch bounds command.

Thanks

Here's the main function if you want to run it yourself:

```
    int main()
    {
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL)); 
    cudaSetDevice(0);

    cudaStream_t s6;
    cudaStreamCreate(&s6);

         float tm[transMatrixSize] = {0.068571, 1, 0.069143, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.069143, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0.003810, 2.000000, 0.004670, -1, 0, 0, 0.003810, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.000000, 0.074743, -2.000000, 0.143315, 1, 0, 2.000000, 0.074743, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 2.000000, 0.074743, -2.000000, 0.074872, -1, 0, 2.000000, 0.074743, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.068571, 1, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0.000218, -1, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.068571, 1, 0.069143, 2.000000, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0.069143, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0.003810, 2.000000, 0.004670, -1, 0, 0, 0.003810, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.000000, 0.074743, -2.000000, 0.143315, 1, 0, 2.000000, 0.074743, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 2.000000, 0.074743, -2.000000, 0.074872, -1, 0, 2.000000, 0.074743, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.068571, 1, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0.000218, -1, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.068571, 1, 0.071701, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.071701, 
    2.000000, 0, 0, 0.020866, 2.000000, 0.021727, -1, 0, 0, 0.020866, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000003, 2.000000, 0.013649, -2.000000, 0.082221, 1, 0.000003, 2.000000, 0.013649, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.000003, 2.000000, 0.013649, -2.000000, 0.013778, -1, 0.000003, 2.000000, 0.013649, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.068571, 1, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0.000218, -1, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.068571, 1, 0.071701, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.071701, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0.020866, 2.000000, 
    0.021727, -1, 0, 0, 0.020866, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000003, 2.000000, 0.013649, -2.000000, 0.082221, 1, 0.000003, 2.000000, 0.013649, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.000003, 2.000000, 0.013649, -2.000000, 0.013778, -1, 0.000003, 2.000000, 0.013649, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.068571, 1, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0.000218, -1, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.068571, 1, 0.076852, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.076852, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0.055205, 2.000000, 0.056066, -1, 0, 0, 0.055205, 
    2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000006, 2.000000, 0.005164, -2.000000, 0.073735, 1, 0.000006, 2.000000, 0.005164, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.000006, 2.000000, 0.005164, -2.000000, 0.005293, -1, 0.000006, 2.000000, 0.005164, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.068571, 1, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0.000218, -1, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.068571, 1, 0.076852, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.076852, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0.055205, 2.000000, 0.056066, -1, 0, 0, 0.055205, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0.000006, 2.000000, 0.005164, -2.000000, 0.073735, 1, 0.000006, 2.000000, 0.005164, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.000006, 2.000000, 0.005164, -2.000000, 0.005293, -1, 0.000006, 2.000000, 0.005164, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.068571, 1, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0.000218, -1, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.068571, 1, 0.069143, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.069143, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0.003810, 2.000000, 0.004670, -1, 0, 0, 0.003810, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.000000, 0.074743, -2.000000, 0.143315, 
    1, 0, 2.000000, 0.074743, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 2.000000, 0.074743, -2.000000, 0.074872, -1, 0, 2.000000, 0.074743, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.068571, 1, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0.000218, -1, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.068571, 1, 0.069143, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.069143, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0.003810, 2.000000, 0.004670, -1, 0, 0, 0.003810, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.000000, 0.074743, -2.000000, 0.143315, 1, 0, 2.000000, 0.074743, -2.000000, 
    0, 0, 0, 2.000000, 0.074743, -2.000000, 0.074872, -1, 0, 2.000000, 0.074743, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.068571, 1, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0.000218, -1, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.068571, 1, 0.071701, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.071701, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0.020866, 2.000000, 0.021727, -1, 0, 0, 0.020866, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000003, 2.000000, 0.013649, -2.000000, 0.082221, 1, 0.000003, 2.000000, 0.013649, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.000003, 2.000000, 0.013649, 
    -2.000000, 0.013778, -1, 0.000003, 2.000000, 0.013649, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.068571, 1, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0.000218, -1, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.068571, 1, 0.071701, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.071701, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0.020866, 2.000000, 0.021727, -1, 0, 0, 0.020866, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000003, 2.000000, 0.013649, -2.000000, 0.082221, 1, 0.000003, 2.000000, 0.013649, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.000003, 2.000000, 0.013649, -2.000000, 0.013778, -1, 0.000003, 2.000000, 
    0.013649, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.068571, 1, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0.000218, -1, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.068571, 1, 0.076852, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.076852, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0.055205, 2.000000, 0.056066, -1, 0, 0, 0.055205, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000006, 2.000000, 0.005164, -2.000000, 0.073735, 1, 0.000006, 2.000000, 0.005164, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.000006, 2.000000, 0.005164, -2.000000, 0.005293, -1, 0.000006, 2.000000, 0.005164, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.068571, 
    1, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0.000218, -1, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.068571, 1, 0.076852, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.076852, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0.055205, 2.000000, 0.056066, -1, 0, 0, 0.055205, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000006, 2.000000, 0.005164, -2.000000, 0.073735, 1, 0.000006, 2.000000, 0.005164, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.000006, 2.000000, 0.005164, -2.000000, 0.005293, -1, 0.000006, 2.000000, 0.005164, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.068571, 1, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0.000218, -1, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.068571, 1, 0.071701, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.071701, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0.020866, 2.000000, 0.021727, -1, 0, 0, 0.020866, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000003, 2.000000, 0.013649, -2.000000, 0.082221, 1, 0.000003, 2.000000, 0.013649, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.000003, 2.000000, 0.013649, -2.000000, 0.013778, -1, 0.000003, 2.000000, 0.013649, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.068571, 1, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 
    0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0.000218, -1, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.068571, 1, 0.071701, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.071701, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0.020866, 2.000000, 0.021727, -1, 0, 0, 0.020866, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000003, 2.000000, 0.013649, -2.000000, 0.082221, 1, 0.000003, 2.000000, 0.013649, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.000003, 2.000000, 0.013649, -2.000000, 0.013778, -1, 0.000003, 2.000000, 0.013649, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.068571, 1, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0.000218, -1, 
    0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.068571, 1, 0.085714, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.085714, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0.114286, 2.000000, 0.115147, -1, 0, 0, 0.114286, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000021, 2.000000, 0.002513, -2.000000, 0.071084, 1, 0.000021, 2.000000, 0.002513, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.000021, 2.000000, 0.002513, -2.000000, 0.002642, -1, 0.000021, 2.000000, 0.002513, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.068571, 1, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0.000218, -1, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0.068571, 1, 0.085714, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.085714, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0.114286, 2.000000, 0.115147, -1, 0, 0, 0.114286, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000021, 2.000000, 0.002513, -2.000000, 0.071084, 1, 0.000021, 2.000000, 0.002513, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.000021, 2.000000, 0.002513, -2.000000, 0.002642, -1, 0.000021, 2.000000, 0.002513, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.068571, 1, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0.000218, -1, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.068571, 1, 
    0.113927, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.113927, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0.302372, 2.000000, 0.303233, -1, 0, 0, 0.302372, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000043, 2.000000, 0.000984, -2.000000, 0.069556, 1, 0.000043, 2.000000, 0.000984, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.000043, 2.000000, 0.000984, -2.000000, 0.001113, -1, 0.000043, 2.000000, 0.000984, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.068571, 1, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0.000218, -1, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.068571, 1, 0.113927, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0.113927, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0.302372, 2.000000, 0.303233, -1, 0, 0, 0.302372, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000043, 2.000000, 0.000984, -2.000000, 0.069556, 1, 0.000043, 2.000000, 0.000984, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.000043, 2.000000, 0.000984, -2.000000, 0.001113, -1, 0.000043, 2.000000, 0.000984, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.068571, 1, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0.000218, -1, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.068571, 1, 0.071701, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.071701, 2.000000, 0, 0, 
    0.020866, 2.000000, 0.021727, -1, 0, 0, 0.020866, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000003, 2.000000, 0.013649, -2.000000, 0.082221, 1, 0.000003, 2.000000, 0.013649, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.000003, 2.000000, 0.013649, -2.000000, 0.013778, -1, 0.000003, 2.000000, 0.013649, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.068571, 1, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0.000218, -1, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.068571, 1, 0.071701, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.071701, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0.020866, 2.000000, 0.021727, -1, 0, 
    0, 0.020866, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000003, 2.000000, 0.013649, -2.000000, 0.082221, 1, 0.000003, 2.000000, 0.013649, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.000003, 2.000000, 0.013649, -2.000000, 0.013778, -1, 0.000003, 2.000000, 0.013649, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.068571, 1, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0.000218, -1, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.068571, 1, 0.085714, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.085714, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0.114286, 2.000000, 0.115147, -1, 0, 0, 0.114286, 2.000000, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0.000021, 2.000000, 0.002513, -2.000000, 0.071084, 1, 0.000021, 2.000000, 0.002513, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.000021, 2.000000, 0.002513, -2.000000, 0.002642, -1, 0.000021, 2.000000, 0.002513, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.068571, 1, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0.000218, -1, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.068571, 1, 0.085714, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.085714, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0.114286, 2.000000, 0.115147, -1, 0, 0, 0.114286, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000021, 2.000000, 0.002513, 
    -2.000000, 0.071084, 1, 0.000021, 2.000000, 0.002513, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.000021, 2.000000, 0.002513, -2.000000, 0.002642, -1, 0.000021, 2.000000, 0.002513, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.068571, 1, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0.000218, -1, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.068571, 1, 0.113927, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.113927, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0.302372, 2.000000, 0.303233, -1, 0, 0, 0.302372, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000043, 2.000000, 0.000984, -2.000000, 0.069556, 1, 0.000043, 2.000000, 
    0.000984, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.000043, 2.000000, 0.000984, -2.000000, 0.001113, -1, 0.000043, 2.000000, 0.000984, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.068571, 1, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0.000218, -1, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.068571, 1, 0.113927, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.113927, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0.302372, 2.000000, 0.303233, -1, 0, 0, 0.302372, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000043, 2.000000, 0.000984, -2.000000, 0.069556, 1, 0.000043, 2.000000, 0.000984, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.000043, 
    2.000000, 0.000984, -2.000000, 0.001113, -1, 0.000043, 2.000000, 0.000984, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.068571, 1, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0.000218, -1, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.068571, 1, 0.076852, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.076852, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0.055205, 2.000000, 0.056066, -1, 0, 0, 0.055205, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000006, 2.000000, 0.005164, -2.000000, 0.073735, 1, 0.000006, 2.000000, 0.005164, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.000006, 2.000000, 0.005164, -2.000000, 0.005293, -1, 
    0.000006, 2.000000, 0.005164, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.068571, 1, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0.000218, -1, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.068571, 1, 0.076852, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.076852, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0.055205, 2.000000, 0.056066, -1, 0, 0, 0.055205, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000006, 2.000000, 0.005164, -2.000000, 0.073735, 1, 0.000006, 2.000000, 0.005164, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.000006, 2.000000, 0.005164, -2.000000, 0.005293, -1, 0.000006, 2.000000, 0.005164, -2.000000, 0, 
    0, 0.068571, 1, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0.000218, -1, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.068571, 1, 0.113927, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.113927, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0.302372, 2.000000, 0.303233, -1, 0, 0, 0.302372, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000043, 2.000000, 0.000984, -2.000000, 0.069556, 1, 0.000043, 2.000000, 0.000984, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.000043, 2.000000, 0.000984, -2.000000, 0.001113, -1, 0.000043, 2.000000, 0.000984, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.068571, 1, 0.068660, -2.000000, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0.000218, -1, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.068571, 1, 0.113927, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.113927, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0.302372, 2.000000, 0.303233, -1, 0, 0, 0.302372, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000043, 2.000000, 0.000984, -2.000000, 0.069556, 1, 0.000043, 2.000000, 0.000984, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.000043, 2.000000, 0.000984, -2.000000, 0.001113, -1, 0.000043, 2.000000, 0.000984, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.068571, 1, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.068660, 
    -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0.000218, -1, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.068571, 1, 0.188571, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.188571, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0.800000, 2.000000, 0.800861, -1, 0, 0, 0.800000, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000085, 2.000000, 0.000441, -2.000000, 0.069013, 1, 0.000085, 2.000000, 0.000441, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.000085, 2.000000, 0.000441, -2.000000, 0.000570, -1, 0.000085, 2.000000, 0.000441, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.068571, 1, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 
    0.000218, -1, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.068571, 1, 0.188571, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.188571, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0.800000, 2.000000, 0.800861, -1, 0, 0, 0.800000, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000085, 2.000000, 0.000441, -2.000000, 0.069013, 1, 0.000085, 2.000000, 0.000441, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.000085, 2.000000, 0.000441, -2.000000, 0.000570, -1, 0.000085, 2.000000, 0.000441, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.068571, 1, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0.000218, -1, 0, 0, 0.000088, 
    -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.068571, 1, 0.076852, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.076852, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0.055205, 2.000000, 0.056066, -1, 0, 0, 0.055205, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000006, 2.000000, 0.005164, -2.000000, 0.073735, 1, 0.000006, 2.000000, 0.005164, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.000006, 2.000000, 0.005164, -2.000000, 0.005293, -1, 0.000006, 2.000000, 0.005164, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.068571, 1, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0.000218, -1, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0.068571, 1, 0.076852, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.076852, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0.055205, 2.000000, 0.056066, -1, 0, 0, 0.055205, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000006, 2.000000, 0.005164, -2.000000, 0.073735, 1, 0.000006, 2.000000, 0.005164, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.000006, 2.000000, 0.005164, -2.000000, 0.005293, -1, 0.000006, 2.000000, 0.005164, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.068571, 1, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0.000218, -1, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.068571, 1, 0.113927, 2.000000, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0.113927, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0.302372, 2.000000, 0.303233, -1, 0, 0, 0.302372, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000043, 2.000000, 0.000984, -2.000000, 0.069556, 1, 0.000043, 2.000000, 0.000984, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.000043, 2.000000, 0.000984, -2.000000, 0.001113, -1, 0.000043, 2.000000, 0.000984, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.068571, 1, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0.000218, -1, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.068571, 1, 0.113927, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.113927, 2.000000, 
    0, 0, 0.302372, 2.000000, 0.303233, -1, 0, 0, 0.302372, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000043, 2.000000, 0.000984, -2.000000, 0.069556, 1, 0.000043, 2.000000, 0.000984, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.000043, 2.000000, 0.000984, -2.000000, 0.001113, -1, 0.000043, 2.000000, 0.000984, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.068571, 1, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0.000218, -1, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.068571, 1, 0.188571, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.188571, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0.800000, 2.000000, 0.800861, 
    -1, 0, 0, 0.800000, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000085, 2.000000, 0.000441, -2.000000, 0.069013, 1, 0.000085, 2.000000, 0.000441, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.000085, 2.000000, 0.000441, -2.000000, 0.000570, -1, 0.000085, 2.000000, 0.000441, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.068571, 1, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0.000218, -1, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.068571, 1, 0.188571, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.188571, 2.000000, 0, 0, 0.800000, 2.000000, 0.800861, -1, 0, 0, 0.800000, 2.000000, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000085, 2.000000, 0.000441, -2.000000, 0.069013, 1, 0.000085, 2.000000, 0.000441, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.000085, 2.000000, 0.000441, -2.000000, 0.000570, -1, 0.000085, 2.000000, 0.000441, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.068571, 1, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.068660, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0.000218, -1, 0, 0, 0.000088, -2.000000, 0, 0, 0, 0};



   float *h_F6 = new float[(iterations)];
    float *h_F50_6 = new float[(iterations)];
    float h_S6 [reps]; for (int i = 0; i < reps; i++) {h_S6 [i] = 0;}; for (int i = 0; i < reps; i++){h_S6 [i] = float(rand());}
    // Device input vectors
    float *d_F6 ;
    float *d_F50_6 ;
    float *d_S6 ;
    float *d_TM6 ;
    // Allocate memory for each vector on GPU
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_F6 , iterations * sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_F50_6 , iterations * sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_S6 , reps * sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_TM6 , transMatrixSize * sizeof(float));
    // Copy host vectors to device
    cudaMemcpyAsync( d_S6 , h_S6 , reps * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, s6 );
    cudaMemcpyAsync( d_TM6 , tm , transMatrixSize * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, s6 );

    bufferleech<<<1, 1024, 0, s6 >>>( d_F6 , d_F50_6 , d_TM6 , d_S6 , reps);

    cudaMemcpyAsync( h_F6 , d_F6 , iterations * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost, s6 );
    cudaMemcpyAsync( h_F50_6 , d_F50_6 , iterations * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost, s6 );

    delete h_F6; delete h_F50_6;

    cudaDeviceReset();
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Have you inspected the generated code? More registers used doesn't automatically mean the algorithm goes faster: if the CUDA compiler didn't use them it means it couldn't or that it didn't need that much. There are lots of cycles in your code, the compiler might have been able to optimize stuff and just keep some stuff in the registers. Profile your kernel against the "other one" and see if you have a gain or a loss. I would be more concerned about the low occupancy, perhaps you have bank conflicts on the shared memory. Use Nsight to assess this.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. How do I inspect the generated code? If you mean low level code, I don't know how to do that?

Comment: IIRC there's a cuobj-dump utility that might just do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[launch bounds](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#launch-bounds) places (indirectly) an upper limit on registers per thread.  It does not force the compiler to use a specific number of registers per thread.

If the compiler only needs 46 registers per thread, launch bounds will not force it to use more.

The fact that you have written "similar" kernels that use more doesn't really say anything.  Innocuous changes in kernel code can result in substantially different register usage.

If you want your program to run faster, use more than 1 threadblock.  That is a considerably more important optimization objective than striving to increase register per thread usage.

There are [binary utilities](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-binary-utilities/index.html#axzz38ahHD8Jv) that allow you to inspect the generated machine code, if you wish.  However this isn't going to be that instructive for understanding register per thread usage, except to confirm it.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Increasing threadblock size isnt an option as the code need to remain in one block so that threads may communicate via shared memory. Do you know any other way to increase registers in my kernel?

Comment: It's a strange request.  Focus on optimizing your code.  The compiler will use more registers (up to the implied maximum from launch bounds) if it finds sensible reasons to do so.  And summarily rejecting the idea of using multiple threadblocks is hobbling your code to a small percentage of the performance available in a GPU.  There are many codes that use shared memory that are not restricted to one threadblock.  You might want to think about ways to partition your algorithm in such a way that pieces can run in parallel, even if it means duplicating shared memory data.